# How to generate an UnmappableCharacterException from CharsetDecoder's .decode()?

Tags: java, character-encoding

[Note: question basically re-edited after a lot of playing around]

In Java, you have `Charset`, defining a character encoding. From a `Charset`, you can obtain two objects:

- a `CharsetEncoder`, to turn a `char` sequence into a `byte` sequence;
- a `CharsetDecoder`, to turn a `byte` sequence into a `char` sequence.

Both of these classes have the following methods defined: `.onUnmappableCharacter()` and `.onMalformedInput()`. If you tell them for each of these to `CodingErrorAction.REPORT` they will throw either of these two exceptions: [`UnmappableCharacterException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/UnmappableCharacterException.html) and [`MalformedInputException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/MalformedInputException.html).

With a `CharsetEncoder`, I am able to generate both of them:

- feed it with a `CharBuffer` containing two high surrogates following one another --> `MalformedInputException`;
- feed it with a `CharBuffer` containing a `char` (or `char` sequence) which the encoding cannot represent: `UnmappableCharacterException`.

With a `CharsetDecoder`:

- feed it with an illegal byte sequence: `MalformedInputException` -- easy to do;
- `UnmappableCharacterException` --> how?

In spite of all my research, I just couldn't do it.

All of this in spite of having [played a lot with `CharsetDecoder`](https://github.com/fge/largetext). I could find no combination of `Charset` and byte sequence able to generare this error...

Is there any at all?

Comment: map any extended character in a utf charset to ascii.

Comment: @jtahlborn uhm, what do you call an "extended character"?

Comment: anything outside the ascii charset, like `ü`.

Comment: @jtahlborn just tried... Still a `MalformedInputException`

Comment: show some example code.

Comment: where's you code which is attempting to generate the UnmappableCharException?

Comment: ah, now i understand the confusion.  you are specifically referring to the `decode()` method, where i was thinking about _encoding_.  that exception makes more sense for encoding, i'm unsure how you would generate it when decoding (it's possible they added it to the api just to make it similar to encoding).

Comment: UnmappableCharacterException doesn't make sense for decoding. It would only be caused during encoding, when you supply a bad character. If an input array gets converted into a bad character, then that falls under the MalformedInputException.

Comment: @AnubianNoob I thought the same about `MalformedInputException` when using a `CharsetEncoder`, and yet...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's just a matter of finding a character set with an unmappable byte sequence.

Take, for example, [`IBM1098`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/x-IBM1098/decode.htm). It can't map the hex bytes

```
0x80
0x81
```

So put these in a `ByteBuffer`, rewind it, and try to decode it.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws CharacterCodingException {
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(8);
        buffer.putInt(0x80);
        buffer.putInt(0x81);
        buffer.position(0);
        Charset charset = Charset.forName("IBM1098");
        CharsetDecoder decoder = charset.newDecoder();
        decoder.decode(buffer);
    }   
}
```

This throws

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.charset.UnmappableCharacterException: Input length = 1
    at java.nio.charset.CoderResult.throwException(CoderResult.java:282)
    at java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder.decode(CharsetDecoder.java:816)
    at com.test.Test.main(Test.java:16)
```

[Ideone.com attempt.](https://ideone.com/HEIUck)

Comment: Uuh... OK, I still don't understand this exception very well it seems... Good find! +516 ;)

Comment: @fge It doesn't seem like it applies to all character sets though. For example, [UTF-8 clearly defines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) what is invalid, but says nothing (as far as I can see) about unmappable character. I would assume that they are all mappable, just some sequences are invalid, ie. malformed.

Comment: I surmised as much, but could not find a charset which had this "unmappable" property. You did, however!

Comment: @fge I got all `availableCharsets` and chose among the most random sounding ones :).

Answer (score 0):

When you supply a character to the decoder, the decoder can tell that a character is not appropriate for the charset and throw a UnmappableCharacterException.

When you supply a byte array to the encoder, is assumes that it has been encoded properly. Thus when it decodes your byte array and gets a bad character, it assumes you have a broken encoder or bad input, which causes a MalformedInputException.

Comment: I _know_ all that, I can produce `MalformedInputException`s at will. What I want to know is how to make a decoder raise `UnmappableCharacterException` if it is possible at all; and if not, a definitive proof as to why it isn't possible.