# Why does Java's CharsetEncoder define .onMalformedInput()/CharsetDecoder define .onUnmappableCharacter()?

Tags: java, character-encoding

A [`CharsetDecoder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html) basically helps decoding a sequence of `bytes` into a sequence of `char`s (see [`Charset#newDecoder()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#newDecoder--)). On the opposite side, a [`CharsetEncoder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetEncoder.html) (see [`Charset#newEncoder()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#newEncoder--)) does the reverse: take a sequence of `char`s, and encode them into a sequence of `byte`s.

`CharsetDecoder` defines `.onMalformedInput()` and it seems logical (some byte sequence may not translate to a valid `char` sequence); but why `.onUnmappableCharacter()` since its input is a byte sequence?

Similarly, `CharsetEncoder` defines `.onUnmappableCharacter()` which is, here again, logical (for instance, if your charset is ASCII, you cannot encode `ö`); but why does it also define `.onMalformedInput()` since its input is a character sequence?

This is all the more intriguing that you cannot obtain an encoder from a decoder and vice versa, and none of these two classes seem to share a common ancestor...

---

**EDIT 1**

It is indeed possible to trigger `.onMalformedInput()` on a `CharsetEncoder`. You "just" have to provide an illegal `char` or `char` sequence. The program below relies on the fact that in UTF-16, a high surrogate must be followed by a low surrogate; here, a two-element char array is built with two high surrogates instead and an attempt to encode it is done. **NOTE how the creation of a `String` from such an ill-formed char sequence throws no exception at all**:

Code:

```
public static void main(final String... args)
    throws CharacterCodingException
{
    boolean found = false;
    char c = '.';

    for (int i = 0; i < 65536; i++) {
        if (Character.isHighSurrogate((char) i)) {
            c = (char) i;
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!found)
        throw new IllegalStateException();

    System.out.println("found: " + Integer.toHexString(c));
    final char[] foo = { c, c };

    new String(foo); // <-- DOES NOT THROW AN EXCEPTION!!!

    final CharsetEncoder encoder = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.newEncoder()
        .onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPORT);

    encoder.encode(CharBuffer.wrap(foo));
}
```

Output:

```
found: d800
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
    at java.nio.charset.CoderResult.throwException(CoderResult.java:277)
    at java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder.encode(CharsetEncoder.java:798)
    at com.github.fge.largetext.LargeText.main(LargeText.java:166)
```

---

**EDIT 2** But now, how about the reverse? From @Kairos's answer below, quoting the manpage:

> UnmappableCharacterException - If the byte sequence starting at the input buffer's current position cannot be mapped to an equivalent character sequence and the current unmappable-character action is CodingErrorAction.REPORT

Now, what is "cannot be mapped to an equivalent character sequence"?

I play quite a bit with `CharsetDecoder`s in [this project](https://github.com/fge/largetext) and have yet to produce such an error. I know how to reproduce an error in which, for instance, you only have two bytes out of a three-byte UTF-8 sequence but this triggers a `MalformedInputException`. All you have to do in this case is restart the decoding from the last known position of the `ByteBuffer`.

Triggering an `UnmappableCharacterException` would basically mean that the *character encoding itself* would allow for an illegal `char` to be generated; or an illegal Unicode code point.

Is this possible at all?

Comment: You bring up a good point. There are few examples even using the method, much less _why_ it is implemented...still looking though.

Comment: @Kairos a real world example can be found in Java 7's `UnixPath` (abstract `Path` implementation of JDK 7 for Unix systems): it uses a `CharsetEncoder` with `.onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.REPORT)`; if the `String` you provide cannot be encoded according to your `Charset.defaultCharset()`, `Paths.get()` will throw an `InvalidPathException` if the encoding detected a character (or sequence of) not mappable to a byte sequence

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the docs for [CharsetEncoder.encode()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetEncoder.html#encode%28java.nio.CharBuffer%29) it states that it throws a MalformedInputException

> If the character sequence starting at the input buffer's current
>   position is not a legal sixteen-bit Unicode sequence and the current malformed-input 
>   action is CodingErrorAction.REPORT

So, you are given the option of providing a [CodingErrorAction](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CodingErrorAction.html) by utilizing [onMalformedInput](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetEncoder.html#onMalformedInput%28java.nio.charset.CodingErrorAction%29) so that if you encounter one of these illegal sixteen-bit Unicode sequences, the provided action will be performed.

Similarly for [CharsetDecoder.decode()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html#decode%28java.nio.ByteBuffer%29)

> UnmappableCharacterException - If the byte sequence starting at the
>   input buffer's current position cannot be mapped to an equivalent
>   character sequence and the current unmappable-character action is
>   CodingErrorAction.REPORT

Comment: An example? Not sure, maybe a string starting with a combining diacritical mark, normally _after_ the: `c` + combining-`^` (`"\u0302"`) = `ĉ`

Comment: Uh, OK, I can see that `.onMalformedInput()` can relate to `char`s, for instance, if you have two `char`s following one another which are an invalid (BE) UTF-16 sequence, for instance, two high surrogates following one another. +1 for that. But how about the reverse? How can you trigger `.onUnmappableCharacter()` from a `CharsetDecoder`?

Comment: @fge You yourself have said it already "if your charset is ASCII, you cannot encode ö". This would be a fitting example during CharsetDecoder.decode() as well.

Comment: @Kairos that would be a `CharsetEncoder` which is used here, not a `CharsetDecoder`; and in this case the triggered action would have been `.onUnmappableCharacter()` -- but on an encoder, not a decoder

Comment: @fge, ah I see. Your above comment asks for it in CharsetDecoder.

Comment: @Kairos well yes -- how can you have an unmappable _character_ while decoding a _byte_ array? Since a decoder tries and turns a byte sequence into a legal char sequence

Comment: @fge, it's not quite a byte _array_ exactly, decode takes a ByteBuffer which can be created from chars with ByteBuffer.putChar().

Comment: Oh, also -- the second extract says "If the byte sequence starting at the input buffer's current position cannot be mapped to an equivalent character sequence and the current unmappable-character action is CodingErrorAction.REPORT" <-- OK, but how does it distinguish a short read from an actual unmappable sequence? Is there such a character encoding?

Comment: @Kairos err no, doesn't quite work that way ;) A `char` is not two `byte`s!

Comment: @Kairos just confirmed in the question edit that it is possible to trigger `.onMalformedInput()` on a `CharsetEncoder`, pity I can't +1 more

Comment: @Kairos I'd love to, except that I want to know how to trigger the reverse too!

Comment: @fge, and that was to get CharsetDecoder to throw an UnmappableCharacterException?

Comment: @Kairos yup... See question edit. I have no clue how to trigger that at the moment

Comment: @Kairos I accepted your answer since it answers half of my problem... The other half I have already asked in another question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22022145/1093528)

Comment: @fge, thanks! I have an idea for your second part and am attempting it now.

Comment: @Kairos if you can answer it, the question linked above will grant +500 for what you find it worth :p I really wish to have an explanative answer

Comment: @fge, you've doomed me to no longer get anything done until i solve this problem :-\. now, why'd you go and do that :-P

Comment: @Kairos don't feel compelled to answer either, heh :p