# Does UTF-8 content could be malformed in Java

Tags: java, utf-8, character-encoding, encoder-decoder, charset

I am trying to create a test case in java to test

```
decoder.onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPLACE);
decoder.onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.REPLACE);
```

I need some character in UTF_8 Charset which are able to test them.

Comment: UTF-8, afaik, is not a character set, but just a character encoding standard - do you need something like explained in Wikipeida: [Invalid sequences and error handling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Invalid_sequences_and_error_handling) ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate an UnmappableCharacterException from CharsetDecoder's .decode()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22022145/how-to-generate-an-unmappablecharacterexception-from-charsetdecoders-decode)

Comment: Malformed input would be any `char` *incorrectly* encoded *as UTF-8*. So any character 0x7F to 0xFF should do it. An umlauted character encoded in an 8 bit encoding would be a good choice

Comment: @user22471702 The word ‘charset’ has long been used as a synonym for a character encoding—[in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/charset/package-summary.html), in the original [MIME definition](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046#section-4.1.2), and in the [UTF-8 definition](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2044#section-3).

Comment: Try some common use cases: Not a UTF-8 byte (e.g. in a corrupted file): add a 0xFF somewhere. Delete a byte (on non ASCII part), so you will have problems. Add over-long sequences (it is common to have \x00 encoded as two bytes (so not to have \x00 in a string. Encode surrogates (as codepoint). Use invalid characters (non-characters). And for testing: use unassigned codes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### tl;dr

UTF-8 can represent virtually any character on earth, which is all the characters in Unicode.

If you're asking if a sample of UTF-8 content could be malformed, yes it can. Lay down some bits in a way than violates the [rules described in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). I assume this would trigger your `onMalformedInput` but I’ve not tried it.

Most possible code points in Unicode have *not* been assigned to any character. Some of those are set aside for [“private use”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas) ([*Klingon*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klingon_scripts), etc.). And some of those are reserved for future use. Perhaps UTF-8 encoded text containing any of those reserved-for-future-use code points would trigger your `onUnmappableCharacter`, but I’ve not tried it.

### Details

> any character which is not included in UTF_8 Charset

You are conflating two different things:

- A **character set** is a collection of characters, each identified by an assigned number called a [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point). This set may encompass the characters of a single human language, or multiple human languages.
- A **character encoding** is a way to represent some text of a particular character set by recording the bits and bytes of the code points for the characters in that text.

[Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) is a character set which seeks to represent the characters of all living and most academically-significant dead languages. Unicode is a superset of all other character sets combined. Currently Unicode 15 has recognized 149,186 characters. Each character is assigned a code point number in a range from zero to just over a million.

[UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) is a character encoding that uses one or more octets to represent each assigned number. UTF-8 can represent any of the over one million possible numbers assignable by Unicode.

So, you would be hard-pressed to find any character used by most any peoples on the earth not already listed in Unicode. And all of those characters can be encoded in UTF-8.